# How to read the return code from a child process

Tags: c++, process, return-value, execv

I use fork and execv to execute a child process. In the parent program, I have this:

```
int status;
wait(&status);
cout << "return code = " << status << endl;
```

Will that wait for the child process to terminate and then display it's return code?

Comment: So far all the answers are wrong, since WEXITSTATUS has not even been mentioned.

Comment: Note that the exit status is encoded as the high-order 8 bits of a 16-bit value, and the signal is encoded as the low-order 8 bits.  If the process did not die of a signal, then the low-order bits are zero; if it did die of a signal, then the high-order bits are zero.  See [`wait()` and `waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) for the official POSIX definition; it doesn't mention sets of 8 bits, but provides macros to get at the status and signal information.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [waitpid()](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/waitpid.3.asp) if want to get status of specified child process. `wait()` will return status of first finished child process.

Comment: If there's a single child, `wait()` works as well as `waitpid()`.  In fact, even if there are multiple children, `wait()` works fine as long as you don't mind which 'corpse' you get first.  If you use `waitpid()` to wait for a specific process that does not terminate, then the process might build up a collection of zombies - processes which are dead but for which the parent process has not yet waited.  Also, be aware that you may have to tinker with SIGCHLD.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it should from what i read http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait

Comment: `wait(&status)` is equivalent to `waitpid(-1, &status, 0)` which will wait for any child process. So as long as there is only one child process, the code will work as expected